# Parenthesis around journal's issue title + editors

Tags: biblatex

As you know, some journals have special issues with issue titles and editors. 
Currently using biblatex I get the following result for this case:

> Danon, Gabi (2008). "Definiteness spreading in the Hebrew construct
>   state". In: Lingua 118.7 (Morphosyntactic mismatches in lexical
>   categories). Ed. by I. Nikolaeva and A. Spencer, pp. 872-906.

However, I would like to have the issue title together with the editors in parenthesis, like this:

> Danon, Gabi (2008). "Definiteness spreading in the Hebrew construct
>   state". In: Lingua 118.7 (Morphosyntactic mismatches in lexical
>   categories. I. Nikolaeva and A. Spencer (eds.)), pp. 872906.

I can remove the colon from the original reference by re-defining the journal+issue bibmacro:

```
\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit}
```

I then I can easily achieve having parenthesis around the issue title alone by declaring

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{issuetitle}{\mkbibparens{\textit{#1}}}
```

But I would like the editor information to be there as well.

Here is a MWE (I use XeLaTeX, but I don't think it matters here):

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp, dashed=true, natbib=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}


\bibliography{danon.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit}

  \DeclareFieldFormat{issuetitle}{\mkbibparens{\textit{#1}}} 

\begin{document}

\cite{Danon}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

And the bibliography file:

```
@Article{Danon,
author = {Gabi Danon},
title = {Definiteness spreading in the {Hebrew} construct state},
journal = {Lingua},
year = {2008},
volume = {118},
number = {7},
pages = {872--906},
issuetitle = {Morphosyntactic mismatches in lexical categories},
editor = {I. Nikolaeva and A. Spencer}
}
```

Comment: Could you show us and example of your `.bib` file so we don't have to re-type it ourselves? Could you also add a real MWE so we can see why you get what you already have. The 'current output' certainly already contains deviations from the standard `authoryear` style.

Comment: Any news here? It should be entirely possible to do what you want. But since the output you get is already non-standard (too a degree that is not explained by the changes you report here) an MWE is really necessary to properly answer the question.

Comment: I added a MWE. You are right that the style file I use produced some non-standard results for the bibliography, but it doesn't really matter for this question, I believe.

Comment: Well, you never know until you see the code. If you had used a highly customised non-standard style, chances would have been that you don't use standard macros and so that Paul's answer does not work for you since it relies on macros of the standard styles.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just wrap the `issuetitle`, because as things stand that gets printed by the `issue` bibmacro, and the editors get printed later. So one needs to redefine the `issue` bibmacro in a way that includes the editors, and then clears the `editor` name field so that it doesn't get printed when `byeditor+others` gets called in the next section of the driver. This is also done in such a way that this only happens if there is a separate `issuetitle`. Thus:

```
\renewbibmacro*{issue}{%
  \iffieldundef{issuetitle}%
  {}%
  {\setunit{\addspace\bibopenparen}%
   \printfield{issuetitle}%
   \newunit%
   \ifnameundef{editor}%
     {}%
     {\printnames{editor}%
      \printtext{\space(}%
      \usebibmacro{editor+othersstrg}%
      \printtext{)}}%
  \printtext{\bibcloseparen\space}%
  \clearname{editor}}}
```

[image: screenshot showing bibliography]

Comment: You can use `\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{(#1)}` for the editor string instead of the hard-coded `(` and `)`.

Comment: Good point -- I just worry about what that might do elsewhere: main point is that it has to be hard parens not `biblatex` inserted parens, because we don't want '[eds.]'!

Comment: Mhhh, it certainly changes all editors to '(ed.)'. That might be wanted or not. Maybe a `\ifentrytype` could help, if it is only in this situation. You are absolutely right, we really need hard-coded `(` and `)` and can't use `\mkbibparens` and friends, horrible as I think it to be.